# Laravel subdomain in shared hosting

Tags: laravel-5, subdomain, shared-hosting

Already I have hosted my laravel project http://1d1s.co and working fine. Now I wanted to create dev environment as a subdomain like http://dev.1d1s.co. Kindly help me to do.

Comment: Are you using Apache ? you can use https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#virtualhost to direct a subdomain to a different `DocumentRoot`. What is you configuration like? if your server runs Ubuntu maybe this answers 
 your question https://askubuntu.com/questions/463618/setting-up-subdomain-on-ubuntu-server

Comment: Its shared hosting.... i have only cpanel access... already created subdomain.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, check if your hosting and DNS provider allow subdomains.

Then, you can folow 
[this example](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html)
 if you're using Apache2

If you're using nginx, try following [this guide](https://hackprogramming.com/how-to-setup-subdomain-or-host-multiple-domains-using-nginx-in-linux-server/)

Comment: Yes... already i created subdomain. i dont have command access for apache server... its just shared hosting..... i have cpanel access....

Comment: @TechMahesh you'd rather to change your hosting provider to one that provides ssh access or something like that... Consider using AWS or Heroku

Comment: The client is not interested to change the hosting.

Comment: @TechMahesh If client wants the functional that is not supported by his hosting provider, and he doesn't want to change the solution to fit technical requirements - it means client does not want this functional.